# Weight painting Issue

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

I am doing some animation on my mesh and notice that the foot is stuck to the ground when i try to move it. I tried to use weight painting on the selected bone but it would not work. 
[image]

Comment: I have noticed that the toe bone is not exactly parented to the mesh how does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As his left foot is correctly rigged you can check how it works. Notice that there are actually 2 bones overlaying on each foot, they are called Toes Control (R and L) and Toes (R and L). So to make it simpler, switch to *Pose* mode, hide the bones called Toes Control (R and L), then switch your mesh to *Weight Paint* mode and check how Toes (R and L) influence your mesh. You can see that Toes.R, contrary to Toes.L, has no influence. So begin to paint the area that is supposed to be influenced by this bone, exactly like Toes.L influence the left foot. You're good.